# Get Character String Written to Custom /dev/ file

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm currently working with a custom device driver that I installed. I'm very new to this and having trouble understanding how to get the data that I write into it from the command line.

For example, I write data to the file like so:

```sh
echo -n "test" > /dev/custom
```

And then I merely want to get the string here, so I can use the characters within:

```c
static ssize_t custom_write (struct file *f, const char *buf, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Test\n");
    return len;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the string in `buf`?

Comment: That's my first thought, but I'm unsure how to access it properly. Most times I've tried I've received some sort of permission error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is in `buf`, but it's in user memory. You need to use `copy_from_user()` to copy to kernel memory.

```
static ssize_t custom_write (struct file *f, const char *buf, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    char custom_buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    size_t custom_buffer_size = len;
    if (custom_buffer_size > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
        custom_buffer_size = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
    }
    if (copy_from_user(custom_buffer, buf, custom_buffer_size) != 0) {
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Test %.*s\n", (int)custom_buffer_size, custom_buffer);
    return custom_buffer_size;
}
```

Comment: For `printk(KERN_ALERT "Test %s\n", custom_buffer);` the string in `custom_buffer[]` is not properly null terminated. `printk(KERN_ALERT, "Test %.*s\n", (int)custom_buffer_size, custom_buffer);` would be better.